# cannot read property 'addBubble' of undefined in here maps in angular 9

Tags: angular, here-api

i'm trying to get started with here maps inside my angular application. So i'd like to place two markers on the map and show an infoBubble when clicking one of them. I took [the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/infobubbles/open-infobubble) as a base for my app but i can't get it work.

The error i get when i click one of the map-markers is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addBubble' of undefined

which is this line inside my code -> `this.ui.addBubble(bubble);`

this is my **map.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private monitoringService: MonitoringService
) {
    this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
        "apikey": "xUrjKBvy5RDYJFnKrP6uxXXXXXXXXXXXXVZ_Y44",
        useHTTPS: true
    });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
// Obtain the default map types from the platform
    this.defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate and display a map
    this.map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
    center: {lat: 51.110620, lng: 10.384862},
    zoom: 7
    });

    this.behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));

    this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, this.defaultLayers);

    this.addInfoBubble(this.map);

}

addInfoBubble(map) {
    this.group = new H.map.Group();

    map.addObject(this.group);

    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    this.group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      let bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      // show info bubble
      this.ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);

    this.addMarkerToGroup(this.group, {lat:53.439, lng:-2.221},
      'Manchester City' + 'City of Manchester Stadium Capacity: 48,000');

    this.addMarkerToGroup(this.group, {lat:53.430, lng:-2.961},
      'Liverpool' + ' Anfield Capacity: 45,362');      
  }


addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
    this.marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
    // add custom data to the marker
    this.marker.setData(html);
    group.addObject(this.marker);
}
```

}

i also included these scripts:

```
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and the 3.1 mapjs-ui.css of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` context is not global when you use it inside a function like that. Try using fat arrow function like below:

```
addInfoBubble(map) {
    this.group = new H.map.Group();

    map.addObject(this.group);

    // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
    this.group.addEventListener('tap', (evt)=> {
      // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
      // for all objects that it contains
      let bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
        // read custom data
        content: evt.target.getData()
      });
      // show info bubble
      this.ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);

    this.addMarkerToGroup(this.group, {lat:53.439, lng:-2.221},
      'Manchester City' + 'City of Manchester Stadium Capacity: 48,000');

    this.addMarkerToGroup(this.group, {lat:53.430, lng:-2.961},
      'Liverpool' + ' Anfield Capacity: 45,362');      
  }
```

Comment: @Sithys, please mark it as correct so that other can reference it as well

Comment: Will do so but it's only possible 15 minutes after question was opened